Cif/Structure File for 3CuCl2 · 2dioxane
I am struggling to get the  CIF/Structure file for 3CuCl2·2dioxane. As I could not find it on ICSD database.
Dioxane=C4H8O2
I will grateful to you if you can help me with this ?

Have you looked at actual literature about this committing? Or any other databases?

ICSD is only for inorganics, you had to look in CCDC. Here it is: CUCDOX01 via https://dx.doi.org/10.5517/cctph54.
